# How to specify the inbox for fetchmail?

Tags: fetchmail

I'm setting up a system calling `fetchmail` from the commandline and specifying that the mail be stored in a specific file which is not `/var/spool/mail/$USERNAME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, fetchmail invokes the local [mail transfer agent (MTA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). That's the program you need to configure to set the location of users's mailbox. If you want to change the place where a specific user's mail is delivered, most MTAs read the file called [`.forward`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.forward#.7E.2F.forward_files) in your home directory. You can put a different path in your own `~/.forward` file (just one line containing the full path of the mailbox file where you want your mail to be delivered).

```
/home/handygandy/mail/incoming
```

You can also write `|someprogram` in your `~/.forward` file to invoke a [mail delivery agent (MDA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent), i.e. a program that reads the mail and determines what to do with it based on custom rules. Two popular MDAs are [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) and [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/).

If you're only receiving mail through fetchmail, rather than go through the local MTA, you can tell fetchmail to invoke an MDA directly. Pass the `-m` option on the command line or use the `mda` setting in `~/.fetchmailrc`. For example, one way to deliver mail directly to `~/mail/incoming` is to put `mda procmail` in `~/.fetchmailrc`, and have a `~/.procmailrc` consisting of

```
DEFAULT=$HOME/mail/incoming
```

Or put `mda maildrop` in `~/.fetchmailrc` and have a `~/.mailfilter` consisting of

```
DEFAULT=$HOME/mail/incoming
```

(The resemblance between procmail and maildrop configuration files doesn't go much further.)

Comment: That would be fine, except strace -f doesn't show fetchmail creating any subprocesses.

Comment: @HandyGandy Fetchmail would only create a subprocess if you tell it to invoke an MDA. If it's talking to an MTA, the MTA is a daemon reached over a local TCP socket.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Just after I hit return,I realised so and check /etc/rc* to find exim4.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC fetchmail doesn't write to mailboxes - by default it uses SMTP on localhost or the configured SMTP server or the configured MDA.

I assume you've not got an MTA configured since you're asking about file locations. But that you're using a non-standard location for the mailfile implies that you've already got an MDA configred - just use that. See the fetchmail man page for specifics.